# method declare error textfielddidbeginediting

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

when i use this method

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

it gives me an error

use of undeclared identifier 'textFieldDidBeginEditing'

tell me the solution..

Comment: pls check whether the class conforms to uitextfielddelegate protocol

Comment: Please show us the code in which you're implementing/calling this method.

Comment: i want to add some kind of animation on textfield.  -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)txtUserName { //Keyboard becomes visible
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, 
                                      scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height - 215 + 50); //resize
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

I think u forgot this:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: i used it. But face the same problem.

Comment: have u used UITextField in your application. if not used then u should not call or use this method